# How to find a string in ansible "retries and until" block?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I am installing some plugins and then checking the status in a command loop. I want to check the result of the status of the command and if the plugins are not installed I want to install it again with the help of retry module.

```
- name: install plugins
  command: "run {{ item }}"
  with_items:
  - install plugins
  - status
  register: result
  until: result.stdout.find("InstallPlugin1 and InstallPlugin2") != -1
  retries: 5
  delay: 10
```

I am using register to save the result and I know register saves the result in results and in this case it will save the result in "results" dict. Now I want to check a string in result of status command in until, which should be the 2nd value of results dictionary but I am not able to grab it. 
when I use

```
debug: msg="{{ result['results'][1]['stdout'] }}"
```

I can see the output of the status command but I dont know how to use this in until module. whenever I use results there it gives an error. I want to use something like

```
until: result['results'][1]['stdout'].find("all systems go") != -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both `run install plugins` and `run status` return something like

```
installed: InstallPlugin1, InstallPlugin2
```

the task below will do the job

```
- name: install plugins
  command: "run {{ item }}"
  loop:
    - install plugins
    - status
  register: result
  until:
    - result.stdout is search('InstallPlugin1')
    - result.stdout is search('InstallPlugin2')
  retries: 5
  delay: 10
```

It's not possible to use the loop if only `run status` returns the confirmation, because the *until* statement is evaluated in each iteration.  An option would be to concatenate the commands. For example

```
- name: install plugins
  command: "run install plugins; run status"
  register: result
  until:
    - result.stdout is search('InstallPlugin1')
    - result.stdout is search('InstallPlugin2')
  retries: 5
  delay: 10
```

---

It's possible to test the registered *result* in each loop. After the loop is done the variable *result* will keep accumulated *result.results*. It might be worth to review it.

```
- debug:
    var: result
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Vladimir, I know until will check the result for each iteration. And in this case the result should be a dictionary as it is mentioned here (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#registering-variables-with-a-loop) . I know the string I want is the second value of the results dictionary. I can actually see it when print the results dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:
`until: "all systems go" in item['stdout']`

The `register` statement you have there will be a list of the aggregate results from all irritations in the `with_items` loop and what you want to conditional on is the `item` itself. Depending on what what you're doing, you might not even need to register that variable.

Comment: So you saying with **until: "all systems go" in item['stdout']** i can capture the second value of results dictionary? because the value I am looking for is in dictionary as my command is in loop.

Comment: I'm saying it will catch it in the current iteration of the loop, the `item["stdout"]` will be re-registered and updated for each iteration through the loop.